# How to access the length of an array within an object within LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, javascript-objects

I am having some troubles with the following:
I have an array in an object in localStorage and I need to find the number of elements contained in the array.

My code is as following

```
for (var i = 0; i < localPosts.length; i++){
        local_tags = window.localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)).tags
        console.log(local_tags);
        for (var f = 0; f < local_tags.length; f++) { // <--- error occurs here
            tagf = local_tags[f]
            console.log(tagf);
            for (var j = 0; j < local_tags.length; j++) {
                if(tagf == tags[j]){
                    print_post(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please excuse code messiness

This is an example myh json file(in Json format(this is stringified before it goes into the loops)):

```
{
"article1": {
    "title": "Hello World!",
    "desc": "This is the first post on this website!",
    "img": "",
    "id": 0,
    "tags": ["1", "3"]
},
"article2":{
    "title": "",
    "desc": "",
    "img": "",
    "id": 1,
    "tags": ["1","2"]
}
```

}

The problem with this code is whenever I try accsessing the parent function i get an error that goes like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

and the log of local_tags returns

```
undefined
```

Thanks for the help, I hope I explained it well!

EDIT: made the error more visible in the code

EDIT2: clarified the JSON data is stringified

EDIT3: Added whole Json file

Comment: for (var j = 0; j < tags.length; j++) --> where is your tags array?

Comment: window.localStorage store json data as **[object Object]**, so you are getting that error.

Comment: I stringify the JSON data before it goes into these loops @AlpeshJikadra

Comment: And then you need to parse it. localStorage only stores strings, so getItem will only return strings or null. And yes your code only throws later on, because trying to access an undefined property from a String is not an error per se.

Comment: can u put the format of data coming in local_tags , which u console out

Comment: @satyampathak this is the error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined which means that local_tags is undfined

Comment: ... because there is no `tags` property on String objects. Parse it.

Comment: @Kaiido is there a command to parse the output or are you referring to JSON.parse()?

Comment: Yes I am referring to `JSON.parse`.

Comment: can you post your full json ?

Comment: Also beware with what you are doing. Accessing StorageItems through their index sounds like a really poor design IMM. What if your user (or one of its plugins) stores some value you didn't expect? You would probably be better storing a full *stringified* Array instead.

Comment: @Kaiido I am probably going to restart my project if i don't get an answer to my question so I will keep it in mind to avoid local storage for this use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some errors,at line `if(tagf == tags[j]){`

Try below code, make some changes as per your requirements

```
window.localStorage.setItem("test_article1",JSON.stringify({"article1": { "title": "Hello World!", "desc": "This is the first post on this website!", "img": "", "id": 0, "tags": ["1", "3"]}}))
localPosts = ["test_article1"];
for (var i = 0; i < localPosts.length; i++){
        local_tags = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)))["article1"]["tags"];
        console.log(local_tags);
        for (var f = 0; f < local_tags.length; f++) { // <--- error occurs here
            tagf = local_tags[f]
            console.log(tagf);
            for (var j = 0; j < local_tags.length; j++) {
                    console.log(local_tags[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code gives me the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` which is on line 4

Comment: I tested this code on Chrome, which browser you use ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is created by tags array

```
for (var j = 0; j < tags.length; j++) {
   if(tagf == tags[j]){
      print_post(i);
   }
}
```

it is not defined tags.length

Comment: Yes, that is an error, However, the Console.log(local_tags); and the subsequent for loop is where the error occurs. I will edit the post to make it clearer